# to Search 11 in [1,2,10,11,111,112] by SQL(mysql)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a column in a table that contains some number offsets like this:

```
my_offsets
[1,2,10,11,111,112]
```

I want query this rows `for search value 11 in [1,2,10,11,111,112]`. How can I do in SQL(mysql)?

Comment: 11 in a varchar(299). Can I use IN operator in a string of numbers separated by comma? I don't think but I will test it. Thanks

Comment: It seems JSON_CONTAINS('[1,2,3,4,5]','1','$') Returns: 1 is correct answer! I will test it now.

Comment: `Can I use IN operator in a string of numbers separated by comma` will not work `[1,2,10,11,111,112]` can be `[1,2,10,11]` or `[11,111,112]` or `[11]` and then you're screwed.

Answer (score 0):

if data **is table**

```
SELECT my_offsets
FROM my_tab
WHERE my_offsets='11'
```

if data **is JSON**

```
SELECT * from my_table
WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(yur_data, '11', '$');
```

example

```
  JSON_CONTAINS('[1,2,3]','3','$') Returns: 1
  JSON_CONTAINS('[1,2,3]','7','$') Returns: 0
```

Comment: I don't think is correct because my_offsets contains different numbers [1,2,10,11,112]. '11' is not equals '[1,2,10,11,112]'.

Comment: make the preconditions clearer than now.
var1) my_offsets='[1,2,10,11,111,112]'.
var2) column in my_tab my_offsets contains values: 1,2,10,11,111,112.
var... Pls show fully what data you have now

Comment: Ok sorry. I edit clearer my question.

Comment: Ok something like this work great: `select 
JSON_CONTAINS('[1,2,10,11,111,112]','11','$');`

Comment: OK) this is not like "have a column"